# Approximating volume of a sphere using spherical cones in the limit

Tags: geometry, riemann-integration, riemann-sphere

[Disclaimer: I am not a mathematician, please bear my naive wordings]

I am looking for a reference that can give me a proof to my simple question: 
Can we approximate the volume of a sphere using spherical cones emanating from the center of the sphere, in the limit (-> infinity) ?

In the limit, the cone size goes infinitely small and each cone can be considered as a Dirac-beam.

I have a feeling that this is true but I am looking for a good reference that could explain most of the steps in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

The infinitesimal cone is not really a Dirac-beam since its volume is a third of base area $A$ times altitude $h$, namely $\frac{1}{3}Ah$, rather than the product $Ah$. The argument is valid and can be formalized in the context of true infinitesimal calculus; see [*Elementary Calculus*](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html).

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail for the clarification and for providing a reference. I found in chapter12 of this book a lot of information that could be useful. If you have any other good reference which can supplement the book you proposed that would be great. 

I also would like to ask, does the Riemannian summation approximation would also be valid to integrate discontinuous functions composed of Diracs (of finite heights) ?

Comment: The Dirac delta function is a tricky thing to work with mathematically.  I think it is more advanced than what you need here.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your answers. I will keep looking and thinking about this question.